# Copy controls from ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dealing with `FormView`.
I have a ridiculous long input form, so i was wondering if there's a way to programmatically copy ALL the controls from `ItemTemplate` to `InsertItemTemplate/UpdateItemTemplate` so I don't have to repeat the all Text Boxes / DDLs etc in the `.aspx` since the information entered is the same for both Update /Insert (I already know I can copy /paste, but the `.aspx` is messy enough already).

I am able to set `InsertItemTemplate = ItemTemplate` and when I set the mode to Insert the fields are all displayed. The problem is that when I try to do a `FindControl` in the submit event I always get null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to hold your layout. Register the control in your webpage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ctrl" TagName="FormControl" Src="FormControl.ascx" %>
```

And add it to the `FormView`:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="False">

  <ItemTemplate>
    <ctrl:FormControlID="MyControl1" runat="server" Mode="Item"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <InsertItemTemplate>
    <ctrl:FormControlID="MyControl2" runat="server" Mode="InsertItem"/>
  </InsertItemTemplate>
</FormView>
```

I added a `Mode` argument because it could be to change the layout inside your control depending on the selected mode.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was needing, just a bit of imagination

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your controls in ItemTemplate into a container - say a panel - you can get to them in code through that panels .Controls property. Iterating over this you could then add them to panels in the other templates... Just an idea... :)

foreach (var item in myItemPanel.controls)
    myInsertPanel.controls.add(item)

If you have nested the original controls inside each others, you'd need to reflect that in the foreach loop...